# Co-creation of subtitles

Tags: webapp-rec

[TWiT](http://twit.tv/twit) broadcasts a weekly podcast in English.
About a day later *pokasta* offers a transcription but it is text only. I would like a video with subtitles that would be comfortable to watch. I would provide the subtitles myself but to do so would take a long time.

Is there a service/site like Напомнить пароль (Notabenoid.Org) but for co-translation and subtitling?

A few people would take a section each, translate and create subtitles for these pieces and later Notabenoid assemble the pieces.

PS Sorry for my bad English. This is exactly the reason I need subtitles. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to use something like [OverStream](http://www.overstream.net/) for general video links. We use [Subyo](http://subyo.com/) for YouTube though and it seems to do the trick.

In response to your comment - you may have to wait until Mozilla Labs finish [this design challenge](http://design-challenge.mozillalabs.com/subtitle/) for collaborative subtitling.

Comment: No. As you create the subtitles, I know.
I would like to find a site on which to create subtitles would be no one, and the team.
Ie take and split the movie into parts and each makes the subtitles on their part, and then combine into one file.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to translate your request back into Russian meaning and then back into English again:

You want to find a technology and community of people to collaboratively subtitle the public videos, possibly in Russian. And you want it to be a web-application, rather than a standalone application.

There are two avenues of research I can think of:
*) Re-purposing Manga transcription site. A lot of people like to subtitle Japanese Manga videos into English and form communities around that. But I don't think you will find big Russian community there

*) A better (but not yet ready fit) is Mozilla's [Universal Subtitles](http://universalsubtitles.org/) project. It is explicitly designed to allow people to subtitle/translate videos and is in an active development phase. You will need to push for Russian community to form around the project, but that would probably be easier than doing it here than on a side of Japanese Manga one.

Udachi.